# How to pass return type as parameter (no reflection?)

Tags: java, generics, interface, return-type

I'm trying to create a framework.

This framework is made to parse data from the internet internally, and supply this to the user of the framework (API)

Per example:

- The framework has a Class BasicUser with (String name, long creation)
- This Class implements an interface called "User" which describes basic behaviour.
- Every time this User gets mentioned somewhere, I call some kind of Listener, giving a "User" Object

Now this is great and all, Since they can access the User, but I want the people who use the framework be able to make their own implementations of User.

I want to not make them do a bunch of wrapping.

Someone who uses my Framework, should be able to change "BasicUser" to a class created by the user (which implements "User").

( `should be able to change "BasicUser"` -> Not able to change the class itself, but instead change the class of the Object that gets created for new users to a different 'User' implementation)

Is it possible to do this without using reflection?

Is it also possible that the "User object" passed to the Listener, can be automatically casted to the Class supplied by the framework user using Generics?

Comment: Do you know what interfaces are / have you examined how they would help your use case?

Comment: @DarthAndroid yes! I do. I use interfaces so my framework can use them internally! I want the user to basically be able to add his own mumbo jumbo around it without wrapping the entire BaseUser, they have no need of the interfaces - They'll never know a "BaseUser" (except for standard name and creation date) even exists, I want to return their own class back to them.

Comment: So if i'm reading this correctly, you have a framework that has methods that take in a "User" object.

the users of your framework would create a class that does not extend BaseUser, but implements User.

your famework has methods that need to return the object back to the user as the same type that they pass in - the type that they created that implements User.

is this correct?

Comment: @AAG basically that, yes. I use `User` internally for lots of things, but the intention is of having the framework user create his own implementation, I internally deal with all the stuff, they get cool objects spit out of their type. (implementing User)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in either an instance of the type, e.g.

```
<T> T getResult(T instance) { ... }

Float result = getResult(Float.valueOf(1.0f));
```

or a generic type which is parameterized with the return type, e.g.

```
<T> T getResult(Class<T> clazz) { ... }

String result = getResult(String.class);
```

or with a parameterized List

```
<T> T getResult(List<T> list) { ... }`.

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Integer result = getResult(list);
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I store the Class<> in a field, could I reference this?
It seems as though, my best plan is when the "framework class" gets instantiated, to give the constructor the Class of the return type already, so I can use the same field to instantiate them somehow?

Comment: @Jordy yep. Just note that if you want to pass in `instanceOfT.getClass()`, that has type `Class<? extends T>`, so the parameter and field you store it in need to have that type too. You can add the `? extends` and still use `T`, though.

Comment: passing in a type as a parameter is a messy way to do this.  Instead, called it with the parameterized type, for example:

    `String result =  this.<String>getResult()`

Comment: @AAG unless you pass an instance of `String` (or `Class<? extends String>`) to that method, there is no way to safely create (or otherwise obtain) a non-null `String` to return.